# Defragmentation - stuck at high percent, SQL and big file drives

Tags: windows, hard-drive, defragment

I have a question regarding fragmentation - I am maintaining a couple of SQL and file servers. All of them store their data on D:\ (for SQL server it makes D:\ drive be actually about 10 files, all being database files). I recently noticed that fragmentation of these drives has gotten really high and I am unable to do much with it as classic `defrag.exe` and `ultradefrag` are only getting the fragmentation % by a tiny bit.

What would be the implications of ignoring the fragmentation levels? Will this cause a serious performance issue?

I understand that it is best to have defrag run on system startup so that no locks to file are present, however this does not seem to be the best 'cost-efficent' solution.

Hope you can help me with that